# How to close my program when exiting the frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having some issues getting my GUI to exit on close. I have tried

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.CLOSE_ON_EXIT);
```

I have tried it with DISPOSE_ON_EXIT and it is not working.

when I run the program without any of that code and I click "X" it closes the window, but it is still running.

When I put that code in it will not compile and I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at InvestmentFrame2.main(InvestmentFrame2.java:103)
```

I have tried reading suggestions on here as well as on other websites. The book I am using to learn this stuff didn't really explain anything about it, but just had it in some example code So I have just been trying some various suggestions.

I couldn't figure out if I maybe needed to import something else or if there is some other issue?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InvestmentFrame2 extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 450;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 250;

    private static final double DEFAULT_RATE = 0;
    private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 0;
    private static final double YEARS = 0;

    private JLabel rateLabel;
    private JLabel balanceLabel;
    private JLabel yearsLabel;

    private JTextField rateField;
    private JTextField balanceField;
    private JTextField yearsField;

    private JButton button;

    private JLabel resultLabel;
    private double balance;

    public InvestmentFrame2()
    {
        balance = INITIAL_BALANCE;
        resultLabel = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance);

        createTextField();
        createButton();
        createPanel();

        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void createTextField()
    {
        rateLabel = new JLabel("Interest Rate: ");
        balanceLabel = new JLabel("Account Balance: ");
        yearsLabel = new JLabel("Number of Years Saving: ");

        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;

        rateField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        rateField.setText ("" + DEFAULT_RATE);

        balanceField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        balanceField.setText("" + INITIAL_BALANCE);

        yearsField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        yearsField.setText("" + YEARS);
    }

    class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(rateField.getText());
            double accountBalance = Double.parseDouble(balanceField.getText());
            double years = Double.parseDouble(yearsField.getText());
            double interest = (accountBalance * rate / 100) * years;
            balance = accountBalance + interest;
            resultLabel.setText("Balance: " + balance);
        }
    }

    private void createButton()
    {
        button = new JButton("Calculate Balance");

        ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    private void createPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(rateLabel);
        panel.add(rateField);

        panel.add(balanceLabel);
        panel.add(balanceField);

        panel.add(yearsLabel);
        panel.add(yearsField);

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(resultLabel);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new InvestmentFrame2();
        frame.setTitle("Savings Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_EXIT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: My IDE also gives a message before I run it that says it can't find the symbol CLOSE_ON_EXIT or DISPOSE_ON_EXIT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to run a class which is uncompilable...`JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_EXIT` doesn't exist.  You are actually looking for `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`

Take a minute to read the [JavaDocs for `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))

> public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation)
>  Sets the
>   operation that will happen by default when the user initiates a
>   "close" on this frame. You must specify one of the following
>   choices:
>   * DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants):
>   Don't do anything; require the program to handle the operation in the
>   windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
>   *
>   HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the
>   frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
>   *
>   DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and
>   dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener
>   objects.
>   * EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the
>   application using the System exit method. Use this only in
>   applications.
>  The value is set to HIDE_ON_CLOSE by default.
>   Changes to the value of this property cause the firing of a property
>   change event, with property name "defaultCloseOperation".

You might also find [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) of some use...

You should also ensure that your UI is created within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InvestmentFrame2 extends JFrame {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 450;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 250;

    private static final double DEFAULT_RATE = 0;
    private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 0;
    private static final double YEARS = 0;

    private JLabel rateLabel;
    private JLabel balanceLabel;
    private JLabel yearsLabel;

    private JTextField rateField;
    private JTextField balanceField;
    private JTextField yearsField;

    private JButton button;

    private JLabel resultLabel;
    private double balance;

    public InvestmentFrame2() {
        balance = INITIAL_BALANCE;
        resultLabel = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance);

        createTextField();
        createButton();
        createPanel();

        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        rateLabel = new JLabel("Interest Rate: ");
        balanceLabel = new JLabel("Account Balance: ");
        yearsLabel = new JLabel("Number of Years Saving: ");

        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;

        rateField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        rateField.setText("" + DEFAULT_RATE);

        balanceField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        balanceField.setText("" + INITIAL_BALANCE);

        yearsField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        yearsField.setText("" + YEARS);
    }

    class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(rateField.getText());
            double accountBalance = Double.parseDouble(balanceField.getText());
            double years = Double.parseDouble(yearsField.getText());
            double interest = (accountBalance * rate / 100) * years;
            balance = accountBalance + interest;
            resultLabel.setText("Balance: " + balance);
        }
    }

    private void createButton() {
        button = new JButton("Calculate Balance");

        ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(rateLabel);
        panel.add(rateField);

        panel.add(balanceLabel);
        panel.add(balanceField);

        panel.add(yearsLabel);
        panel.add(yearsField);

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(resultLabel);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new InvestmentFrame2();
        frame.setTitle("Savings Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Compiles and runs just fine for me...

Comment: I will check out those sources, but I initially tried it with EXIT_ON_CLOSE.  and it still would not compile, so after reading some other questions on here i thought I would try the DISPOSE_ON_EXIT.

Comment: @twjohns29 Really, compiled and run just fine for me...especially considering I've been using it since Java 1.3...

Comment: Well that is frustrating. I am using on NetBeans IDE 8.0. I'm not sure if that could have anything to do with it, but It gives a message in the text editor that it can't find the variable CLOSE_ON_EXIT.

Comment: I would argue that **`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`** is the best way to go here.  When the user closes the (last) window, the VM will end.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for a demo that launches 3 frames.  The VM will exit after the last frame is closed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's a valid point but would require more context

Comment: @twjohns29 I updated, compiled and ran you example from Netbeans 8.  It's not finding `CLOSE_ON_EXIT` because it's not a valid property...see the Java Docs for a list of valid properties...

Comment: The thing is, if the VM does **not** exit on window close, but keeps running, it indicates an application thread that should be cleaned up prior to exit.  It might be something as harmless as a timer for an animation, but best track it down, and ensure it is accounted for one way or another. ..is the context I was thinking. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Not disagreeing, but (forbid) you have two windows open, you may want the "main" window to always exit the program, for example. But I agree, it's a great way of trapping renegade code ;)

Comment: *"but (forbid) you have two windows open, you may want the "main" window to always exit the program, for example."*  Huh..  Hadn't thought of that.  I usually design my apps with secondary top-level containers either being a full screen `JWindow` (that the user clicks, presses the esc key etc. to close) or modal dialogs that mean the user has to attend to them before proceeding.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep, I prefer single "main" window concepts as well

Comment: got it EXIT_ON_CLOSE. Thanks